# Why are my KnockKnock jokes out of order here (Java Networking code)?

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm doing a project where I have modified the  [sample Java networking code from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) , which is a networked Knock-Knock joke application.

I want to have it run by itself. Here is my code for the modified KnockKnockServer :

```
import java.net.*;


public class FixedMessageSequenceServer extends Thread {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FixedMessageSequenceServer");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  , InterruptedException {

        logger.debug("This is a DEBUG message in Server ");
        int jokeLocation;

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        FixedMessageSequenceProtocol kkp = new FixedMessageSequenceProtocol(1);

        outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);


        try{ 
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(inputLine);
             outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
             out.println(outputLine);
             if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        }catch(SocketException so) {


        try {  /* boilerplate code for other functionality I needed*/
      } catch (IOException  exp ) {  
         exp.printStackTrace();
}    
 }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And the following is my client-side :

```
public class FixedMessageSequenceClient {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FixedMessageSequenceClient");

  static String KKJokes[] =  { "Who's there?", "Turnip who?", "y", 
                               "Who's there?", "Little Old Lady who?", "y", 
              /* boilerplate code */
                               "Who's there?", "Who who", "y"};

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        logger.debug("This is a DEBUG message in Client-Side");

    int startPosition = 0;    

    try {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File ("somenumber.txt"));

         while(scan.hasNext()) {
            startPosition = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            System.out.println("The start position is : " + startPosition + "! ");
          }    

    } catch (Exception io) {}

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
      kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
      out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader ( kkSocket.getInputStream()  ));   

      for (int i = startPosition; i < KKJokes.length ; i++) {
        try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);        }
        catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        out.println(KKJokes[i % KKJokes.length ]); 
        String fromServer = br.readLine();  
        System.out.println ( fromServer )  ;   
      }

      out.println("Bye");

      System.out.println ("Bye" );

      out.close();
      kkSocket.close();  
    } catch ( IOException io ){
       System.err.println("Calling IO . toString " + io.toString());  
       System.exit(1);
    }    
    }
```

Finally, I slightly modified the Protocol.java class ([link here at Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4pTj3GwR)   ) to be able to take-in the joke-position. This class just has a large multiple-case if-then loop (almost like a complex switch statement), that takes care of the joke sequence.

My issue is that when I run my code, the order is incorrect. Here is how it looks when output :

> ```
> The start position is : 3!
> Knock! Knock!
> Little Old Lady
> I didn't know you could yodel! Want another? (y/n)
> Knock! Knock!
> Doctor
> Is there an owl doctor? Want another? (y/n)
> Knock! Knock!
> Teacher
> Teacher who says do ur HW please Want another? (y/n)
> Knock! Knock!
> You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
> You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
> You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
> Dog
> You're supposed to say "Dog who?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
> You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
> Dog
> You're supposed to say "Dog who?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
> ```

For the full version of the classes, please see the following pastebin links :

[FixedMessageSequenceProtocol.java](http://pastebin.com/4pTj3GwR)

[FixedMessageSequenceServer.java](http://pastebin.com/qgTsHVMW)

[FixedMessageSequenceClient.java](http://pastebin.com/AzaveEv5)

any tips appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug your code by setting break points?

Comment: Please reduce this wall of code to a short example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @EJP - thanks, noted

Comment: Hi @coffee.  I'm keen to help out (see answer below) and thought posting the sequence of communications might help make the answer clearer.  Can I clarify - is the client code you posted ***exactly*** the same as that giving the output?  The line `out.println(KKJokes[i % KKJokes.length ]);` implies that `i` might be greater than `KKJokes.length` - which would make sense given the output, but the code sample has it in a `for` loop where that can never happen.

Comment: Also - the strings in `KKJokes` don't match the output we see - I'd expect to see members for `Doctor who` and `Teacher who` in there.  i'll add the output sequence to my answer, but please confirm the exact client code otherwise at the moment, the sequence doesn't make sense.

Comment: OK - worked it out - the comment where you have put `/* boilerplate code */` is actually crucial to why you see what you do.  I took a look at the linked code and worked it out.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @JRichardSnape - Thanks so much ! I'm on a mobile device at the moment, but I'll confirm as soon as I get back to my work-laptop.   Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

Your code in the post ***does not match*** the code in your link.  This makes the question incredibly difficult to answer and misleading.

It also means that the reason for your problem is simply a typo - you have  `"Who's there"` in your Client code instead of `"Who's there?"`.  I leave the original answer below, because if contains good information about why putting these hard coded strings in your client is a bad idea.  Your code cycles through `KKJokes` as I think you intend, but there is a typo in `KKJokes[12]`

#### Sequence of events:

Client initialises with `startPosition` set to `3` - i.e. starting with the `"Who's there?"` for the little old lady joke in `KKJokes`

Server initialises [] with `currentJoke` set to `1` i.e. the old lady joke

Note that the client prints all the server messages (`S:`) to `stdout` which you reproduce in output in the OP.

```
Server: Knock knock                                    
Client (1 sec later): Who's there ? 
S: Little Old Lady                                     
C (1 sec later): Little Old Lady who? 
S: I didn't know you could yodel! Want another? (y/n)  
C: y   
S: Knock! Knock!
C: Who's there?
S: Doctor
C: Doctor who?
S: Is there an owl doctor? Want another? (y/n)
C: y
S: Knock! Knock!
C: Who's there?
S: Teacher
C: Teacher who?
S: Teacher who says do ur HW please Want another? (y/n)
C: y
S: Knock! Knock!
C: Who's there           <------ TYPO HERE - NO QUESTION MARK !!! ---------
S: You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
C: Dog who?
S: You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
C: y
S: You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
C: Who's there?  
S: Dog
C: Firefighter who?
S: You're supposed to say "Dog who?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
C: y                                            
S: You're supposed to say "Who's there?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
C: Who's There?         
S: Dog
C: Zoologist who? 
S: You're supposed to say "Dog who?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
C: y
```

---

#### Original answer

The underlying reason that your output is out of order because in your client you do not process what you receive on its input.  So, your client just carries on regardless of what your server is doing.  Sometimes, the messages just happen to hit the sequence that the server expects, so you get some output that looks nearly correct, but the jokes in the wrong order.

Here are the main issues with the code:

1. When the client receives any message from the server it just prints it (`fromServer`), it does not process it or change anything based on what it receives.  You set up a client input stream (that I guess should be "listening" for the words "knock knock")

   ```
   br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader ( kkSocket.getInputStream()  ));
   ```

   You just loop through your responses with a `1000` millisecond delay followed by waiting for *whatever the server sends* and then you send the next response in the list.  The server responds to these correctly,  sometimes, if the response happens to be what its waiting for (by coincidence), telling the next bit of the joke, sometimes telling you "You're supposed to say Who's There?!".  If you look at the [code for the client](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java) in the example you link to - you will see that it has a line

   ```
   while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)
   ```

   which is the client waiting for something from the server (either clue or punchline).  If it receives `"bye"` it ends the program, otherwise it sends user input.  If you want to send automated responses instead of user input, you probably need to have something equivalent in your code - e.g. process `fromServer` (perhaps in combination with some state that tells you what stage you are in the joke - e.g. at clue stage or punchline stage) and then send based on that e.g. introduce a variable `LOCAL_JOKE_STATE` (`0` initially, `1` if you've asked "who's there?" and `2` if you've asked "XXXX Who?")

   ```
   if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
        break;

   if (LOCAL_JOKE_STATE == 0)
   {
      out.println("Who's there?");
      LOCAL_JOKE_STATE = 1;
   }
   else if (LOCAL_JOKE_STATE == 1)
   {
      out.println(fromServer + " who?");
      LOCAL_JOKE_STATE = 2;
   }
   else
   {
      out.println("y"); // get another joke
      LOCAL_JOKE_STATE = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Your client is intialised with hard-coded responses to particular jokes - rather than responding to whatever the clue is.  This is generally a bad idea and breaks the point of client-server communication in this case - it would be like a conversation where one party responded in a preset sequence to whatever question was asked, leading to confused, out of sequence responses, but that may coincide e.g.

   > Q (server) : *"Do you enjoy the British weather?"*
   >
   > A (client) : *"Apples"*
   >
   > Q (server) : *"How do you find the lack of a proper summer?"*
   >
   > A (client) : *"Because they're green"*
   >
   > Q (server) : *"How about the feel of autumn leaves under your feet?"*
   >
   > A (client) : *"The crunch is wonderful"*

   Again, [look at the example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java), there are no hard coded string arrays there.
3. You set up your `FixedMessageSequenceProtocol` object to start at `1`.  In Java, arrays are zero indexed - so the server will never give the clue to "tell" the `turnip` joke.  Of course, it's perfectly fine to start the jokes from somewhere else in the list.  From your question, I think maybe this is the customisation you are trying to make?

All in all - there are some pretty fundamental errors in this code, which is trying to perform a (reasonably) sophisticated task.  I suggest that you try getting an exact replica of the code from the site you link working and then very gradually change one thing at a time until either it does what you want, or you hit a small and specific problem which you can ask a question about.

If the main customisation you want to make is for the Protocol to take a start point - simply change that as you have - that's fine.  Leave the rest the same - it should all still work.

Comment: It works !!  I just reran it(after adding in the missing question-mark).  I will continue along and fix it more with your suggestions (such as avoiding hard-coded Strings ).  Many a Thank You !

Comment: In regards to starting the jokes from anywhere in the list - correct, I am planning to implement this also. This will be part of an application where I use logging (logback.jar) to have an external program (call it "superParent" ) restart this KnockKnock code if it dies (and restart at correct location).